# Android activity stack dependency when process is killed

Tags: android, process, android-activity, lifecycle

Let's say there is an `Activity A1` of `Process P1` and `Activity A1` launched `Activity A2` of `Process P2`. The Activity A2 will need to handle quite a lot of things that make the system have to kill P1 for RAM. I wonder what will happen.

As I can see now is that if I force kill `Process P1` through `Application Manager` after `Activity A2` has been launched, when I exit the Settings screen, Activity A2 is gone, too.

The activity stack looks like this before I hit the "Force Stop" button:

```
Home -> A1 -> A2 -> Settings -> Apps -> App info(of P1)
```

After I hit it, it seems that it will look like this:

```
Home -> Settings -> Apps -> App info
```

Though I only killed the Process of A1, but A2 is destroyed too.

Everything goes well. I think no one hopes A2 is still alive when A1 is destroyed. But I wonder if it is possible that A2 is kept alive after A1 is killed, and my program have to look into such situation:

```
Home -> A2
```

When A2 is finished, A1 will be created to accept the result from A2.

---

Did some more "research". If the A1 launches A2, and when memory is low, the 4.0.3 emulator will kill P2 instead of P1. That is A2 will be closed, even though it is the foreground activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity when launched are saved on the Back-Stack, every activity surfed over is saved on this stack,  finish() method can be used to kill the activity when moving on to the another activity, so the that another instance of the same activity is not pushed on the stack again, when surfed backed to the same activity.

For eg:

```
A1             ---->            A2            ----->             A3
```

1st instance of A1 goes in backstack
1st instance of A2 goes in backstack
1st instance of A3 goes in backstack

```
A1             <----            A2            <-----            A3
```

2nd instance of A1 goes in backstack
2nd instance of A2 goes in backstack
2nd instance of A3 goes in backstack

So when you are not using the finish() method, there is no way that killing of A1 kills A2. A2 survives on the stack.

Comment: But we can kill an Activity on the stack by killing its process.

Comment: So if process of Activity1 is killed then the activity is also killed, but that shouldnt effect the state of Activity2 on the stack... isnt it !

Comment: @KumaVivekMitra But actually it does affect. It is reasonable, though seems to be undocumented. You can try it yourself. As long as A2 is opened by A1, it would be very hard to handle if A2 is kept when A1's process is killed.

Comment: Ok...i will surely try this..thanks for sharing the knowledge